# CloudKit Server-to-Server authentication with delphi?

Tags: delphi, cloudkit, ecdsa, server-to-server

I saw the article yesterday on Apple CloudKit and the new server to server solution. See link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247436/cloudkit-server-to-server-authentication).

Is there anyone who knows an up-to-date way how to calculate ECDSA in Delphi 10 Seattle ?

I did not find yet any particular unit to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you can't find a Delphi unit that does the calculation for you, then you might have to find some non-Delphi code that does it. The question you linked to indicates that there's some Python code for it. You might have to **write some code yourself** if you want a Delphi version. If you're having trouble reading Python or writing the equivalent Delphi, then post a specific question here.