# 401 Error on CloudKit Server-to-Server Authentication on Node JS

Tags: cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services, server-to-server, cloudkit-js

I'm trying to query my public CloudKit database using server-to-server authentication. I've generated the key according to Apple's docs, but no matter what I do I get this error:

```
401 - Unauthorized

data: {
  uuid: '...',
  serverErrorCode: 'AUTHENTICATION_FAILED',
  reason: 'no auth method found'
}
```

As far as I can tell, I've set everything up [per the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/SettingUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH24-SW1), but obviously I'm doing something wrong. Here's what I've got in my Node app so far:

```
let date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[Z]')
let domain = 'https://api.apple-cloudkit.com'
let subpath = '/database/1/iCloud.<my container>/development/public/users/current'

let key = fs.readFileSync(__dirname +'/../eckey.pem', 'utf8')
let keyID = 'abc123...'

let requestBody = ''
let bodyHash = crypto.createHash('SHA256').update(requestBody).digest('base64')

let message = date+':'+bodyHash+':'+subpath

let signature = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256').update(message).sign(key, 'base64')

let headers = {
  'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-KeyID': keyID,
  'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-ISO8601Date': date,
  'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-SignatureV1': signature
}

try{
  await axios.post(domain+subpath, requestBody, { headers: headers })
  console.log('--- :) ---')
}catch(error){
  console.log('=== :( ===')
  console.log(error)
}
```

I've already reviewed [this helpful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247436/cloudkit-server-to-server-authentication), but I'm still stuck.

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a ton of troubleshooting to figure this out, but for the sake of posterity, here's what I had wrong:

**=== Fix # 1 ===**

My date was generating local time which was inaccurate because the format implies Zulu/UTC time (because of the `Z`).

The fix was to add `.utc()` to the Moment:

```
let date = moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[Z]')
```

**=== Fix # 2 ===**

Apparently Axios didn't like how I was formatting the request. Changing it to this (with the `baseURL` and `url` separate) works:

```
let response = await axios({ 
  method: 'post', 
  baseURL: baseURL, 
  url: '/records/modify', 
  data: query, 
  headers: headers 
})
```

Seems to be working great now with these fixes in place.

Comment: can you post the full working code? your fix #2 seems to be for a different problem from the original question